# Structuring Composed Bayesian Programs

Tags: bayesian, stan

I am considering writing some stan code to predict soccer game outcomes. More specifically, I thought that modelling the two halves of a game separately and then combining them would be an interesting approach.

My question is: What is the best way generally, to model composed data like this and why?

Some possibilities:

- Use the data of all components(first half, second half, sum, difference, etc.) for the likelihood in one single analysis. For example, model the score for the first half, the score for the second half, as well as their difference and sums in a MCMC run so that their likelihoods are 'aware' of each other.
- Model the first half separately. Then in another MCMC run, create a separate model for the second half including the data of the first half results, and so on for all components such as the goal sums, differences, etc.

My preferred approach has been the first, as I thought that doing everything in one model containing all components would best find the joint distributions of the likelihood, but I am curious if the second approach, besides being possibly more cumbersome has any other downsides.